# Rename dataset based on external feature dataset

Tags: r

I have this sample dataset:

```
v1 v2 v3
2 3 4
5 6 7
```

And a feature dataset

```
v1 v2
1 weight
2 height
3 age
```

can you please advise the best way to rename the dataset columns based on the feature dataset?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `colnames`:

```
colnames(df1) <- df2$v2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use:

```
 library(dplyr)
 df1 %>%
     rename_all(~ df2$v2)
```